# QtQuick 1.1 Floating Rectangles

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qt4.8

I'm using QtQuick 1.1 with Qt 4.8 on an embedded Linux Plattform. I have somekind of Desktop where dynamically created Rectangles are arranged in a Grid - this Grid is inside a Flickable.

```
Flickable{
  anchors.fill: parent
  contentHeight: homegrid.height
  flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
  clip:true
  Grid{
     anchors.left: parent.left
     anchors.top: parent.top
     columns: 4
     flow: GridView.LeftToRight
     id: homegrid
     //new items get pushed to this grid
  }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

When i create 2 more items, i push them to the end of the grid which looks like this:

[image]

Taht's my current State. But now i need to get categories in this Grid and i need to be able to push new items to each category. Should look like:

[image]

And after adding two items to the red category:

[image]

How can i arrange containers in a grid where the containers automatically break at the end of each row?

**Solution:**

1. Using a GridView

`GridView{
      model: myDesktopModel
      delegate: HomeLinkeDelegate { id: homeLinkDelegate }
    }`

2. defining the list in c++

`QList<QObject*> objectList;`

The List can be sorted (by Colors).

3. Register the List

`viewer->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myDesktopModel",QVariant::fromValue(this->objectList));`

When the List is modified, you have to register it again - than the GridView refreshes.

More information about GridView: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-gridview.html#model-prop

More information about QObjectList-based model http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativemodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model

Comment: It seems like the "should look like" image contradicts what you said about wanting the automatic breaking. Do you mean that you want the last item of a certain colour to the last on that row, and that the next colour begins on a new row?

Comment: Items of the same color should be grouped, when there is not enough space in one row - it should automatically break (last picture after n1). One row should always hold 4 Items (except last row)

Comment: What's your problem here ? What did you try and what was the result ?
It seems to me that what you want is the normal behaviour of a `Grid`, no additional code is needed.

Comment: I need to seperate the Grid in categories - which means when i want to add a red item, it should be placed after the last red one. When i get a green item it should be placed after the last green one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't choose the position of items in a `Grid` from QML. You'd be better off using a [`GridView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html) and creating your own custom [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) so that you can choose insert the items at the correct index in the model. Or, as @GrecKo mentioned, use a `ListModel` and call the [`insert()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#insert-method) function.

If you end up choosing the `QAbstractItemModel` approach, see [Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass) for more information.

Comment: Thats not working the way i need it. It causes a break after each grid

Comment: Ok.. it was quite confusing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: a `GridView` with a model or a `Grid` and a `Repeater` with a model.
Although here OP put the `Grid` in a `Flickable` so `GridView seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Note that this can be done without implementing a c++ `QAbstractItemModel`, a simple `ListModel` in QML is enough with calling the `insert` method.
Shameless plug : you could also use `ListModel` (or a custom c++ model) with my [SortFilterProxyModel library](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel) and sort on your color role, this way you don't even need to find out the correct position to insert a new element, you can just append it to your source model.

Comment: Got it working with a `GridView` which uses a C++ `QList<QObject*>`  which is registered via `viewer->rootContext()->setContextProperty`. On getting a new Item i sort the `QList` and register the list again, which causes a reload of the GridView.